# Mankind or the mankind?

Tags: articles

According to Google Ngram, “mankind” and “humankind” are much more popular than “the mankind” or “the humankind”; however, the popularity of “the mankind” seems to be on the increase (it tripled since 1950-s).

Since there is but one mankind, shouldn’t one expect “the mankind” to be more popular?

What difference is there between these usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zak, you are not interpreting Google Ngram results correctly. Yes, 'the mankind' tripled between 1950 and 2000, but it tripled from 0.00000150% to 0.00000550%. That is small, and that's the increased frequency! Three times a vanishingly small frequency is still vanishingly small, and clicking on the Google search link (the mankind) under the graph shows precisely two results - two books whose titles are 'The ManKind Project: Primary Integration Training Facilitator Manual' and 'The mankind quarterly - Volume 30'.

Comment: Well, some Dr. George Joseph K. PhD (!) in his book “THE BEST MESSAGE FOR MANKIND” uses sentences like “He has a plan to save the mankind.” I heard that native speakers never make mistakes with articles!
I mean, how serious this mistake can be if it is made by a PhD?

Comment: By the way, why is the indefinite  article missing in your profile description: 

“Financial governance and compliance officer in (?) large legal organisation.”
P.S. Please pardon my ineptitude with articles.

Comment: That is a self-published religious tract of very dubious quality. Dr. George Joseph K PhD secured his PhD in Political Science from the University of Madras, India, in 1992. He, of the curious single-letter surname, has emitted numerous works of a Christian type, published by the "God Jesus Proof Academy", some of which are available on Google Books (and nowhere else that I can see). A cursory look shows plenty of basic English errors, e.g. "everything consist in Christ".

Comment: My profile description is intended to be of short-note form, in which articles may be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is precisely because there is only one "mankind" that you don't use an article. There's no need to distinguish whether it's one specific mankind or any of many mankinds out there.

This is true of other collective words that do not have multiple instances. If you are talking about, say, "freedom" in general, you might say "Freedom is what makes our country great." You don't say, "The freedom ..." Likewise we say, for example, "Oxygen is necessary for human life", not "The oxygen ..."

Note there's a difference between when we're using a word in a universal sense and when we're talking about some specific group. For example, if you want to talk about all male human beings, you say "men" with no article. Like, "Men are slobs." But if you are talking about a specific group of men, you use "the", like, "The men in my town are slobs." Note that the qualifier doesn't necessarily have to be part of the sentence if it's understood from context. Like, "The people in Ruritania wear colorful clothing. The men usually wear red and orange and the women wear purple and green."

Like many rules in English, there are exceptions. There's only one universe, but we say "the universe", not just "universe". Like, "The universe is vast", not "Universe is vast".

Comment: We wouldn't say, "Christians opened a new era of the mankind". We'd say, "Christians opened a new era of mankind." Nor would we say that pagans are one mankind and Christians are another, so that there are two mankinds that must be distinguished. There is only one mankind. If someone wanted to say that this group of people -- Christians or whomever -- were "a new mankind", then okay, you might talk about "the old mankind" and "the new mankind" with an article like that. But that would be an unusual and non-standard use of the word "mankind".

Comment: I’m sorry for my mistyped previous comment, which I removed. But there are hundreds of sentences like this on websites like “ReversoContent” – can they all be wrong?

Comment: Could you link me to a specific example, or cut and paste it in?

Comment: The following sentences can be found at http://context.reverso.net (a contextual dictionary for interpreters): 
“Experts consider only several tens of breakthrough technologies to exist that had significantly changed the life of the mankind in the XX century.”
“For the mankind to survive, we have to learn to think in a new way”
“We're going to arrange a few hot days for the mankind.” Et c. 
Of course, I no longer suggest that such sentences are right; I wonder though how serious such mistakes are.

Comment: The examples you give are simply wrong. No fluent English speaker would use "the" in those cases. I'm cautious about saying that "the mankind" is always wrong. There might be contexts or examples that I'm not thinking of. But those examples ... no, they're wrong. Apparently these sentences are translations from other languages? If they're computer translations, it wouldn't be surprising for them to have this sort of mistake.